# Multiple Increments for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Code should increment or decrement his own input, for diameter should work only button for diameter etc. But every click increment all inputs

The problem is every click increment all inputs that i want to change

```
const [countDiameter,setCountDiameter] = useState(1);
    const [countFriction,setCountFriction] = useState(1);
    const [countRobotsQnt, setCountRobotsQnt] = useState(1);
    const [countSimulationTime, setCountSimulationTime] = useState(1);

    const incrementCount = () =>{
      setCount(countDiameter + 1);
    };

    const decrementCount = (i) =>{
      if(countDiameter>0){setCount(countDiameter -1);}
    };
```

```
<div className='inputForm'>
                    <input type="number" id='InputDiameter' pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$" value = {count}  onChange={(event) =>{ setCount(event.target.value) }}/>
                    <label for="InputDiameter" className='static-value'>w</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className='ButtonCount' onClick={incrementCount}><button type='button'><span className="countText">+</span></button></div>
                  <div className='ButtonCount' onClick={decrementCount}><button type='button'><span className="countText">-</span></button></div>
                </div>

<div className='inputForm'>
                    <input type="number" id='InputNumber' pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$" value = {count}  onChange={(event) =>{ setCount(event.target.value) }}/>
                    <label for="inputNumber" className='static-value'>qnt</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className='ButtonCount' onClick={incrementCount}><button type='button'><span className="countText">+</span></button></div>
                  <div className='ButtonCount' onClick={decrementCount}><button type='button'><span className="countText">-</span></button></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You are using a *single* state variable for *multiple* inputs.

Comment: Should i write counter for every input?

Comment: If the user is supposed to be able to change two values independently of each other, you obviously need two state variables to keep track of both.

Comment: yeah, but do i have to write a new increment function for other changeable inputs?

Comment: At your actual level of knowledge, yes.

Comment: Ideally you could write only one increment and decrement function and pass the setWhatever function to it. But that would require that you were more familiar with functional programming concepts.

Comment: I got it , it's my first experience in reactj, and it wasn't so hard in my head.Sadly,  i thougt it is possible for me to do it

Comment: Here's one way to solve this: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: if the inputs are visually same, why not to create a separate Input component that will have only 1 state variable value, setValue; and will be reusable

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with React, but according to the comments above, I would have tried the following:
First, set a generic decrement and increment function that accepts a state and a setter function.

```js
const incrementState = (setter, state)=>{
    setter(state + 1)
}
const decrementState = (setter, state)=>{
    if (state > 0) {
        setter(state - 1);
    }
}

[diameter, setDiameter] = setState(1/*or your desired initial value*/)
```

In your *HTML* code, you can then call your decrement/increment function by passing the above parameters to this function:

```html
<div className='inputForm'>
    <input type="number" id='InputDiameter' pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$" value={diameter} onChange={(event)=>{
    setDiameter(event.target.value) }}/>
    <label for="InputDiameter" className='static-value'>w</label>
</div>
<div className='ButtonCount' onClick={incrementState(setDiameter,diameter)}><button type='button'><span
            className="countText">+</span></button></div>
<div className='ButtonCount' onClick={decrementState(setDiameter,diameter)}><button type='button'><span
            className="countText">-</span></button></div>
</div>
```